# iOS: How to stop a background thread from updating UI in the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, uiimageview, lazy-loading

I implement a UITableView of UIImageView cells, each of which periodically refreshes itself every 5 seconds via NSTimer. Each image is loaded from a server in the background thread, and from that background thread I also update the UI, displaying the new image, by calling `performSelectorOnMainThread`. So far so good.

Currently I face a problem when I don't wait until an image is loaded at a current cell and I scroll down quickly to a new cell. That new cell, however, displays an image of a previous cell instead of the new cell's. Although the next round of NSTimer will correctly display the image, but this can confuse users at first.

The problem would be disappear if I don't reuse UITableView's cells, but given the number of cells to be displayed in my app, this is not an option.

So the only solution I can think of is to cancel (or kill) the background thread that is going to display an old image if I know that a user performs the scrolling action.

I wonder that this might not be the best practice and, therefore, seek for your advices.

(I also can't use SDWebImage because my requirement is to display a set of images in loop loaded from a server)

```
// In MyViewController.m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    NSTimer* timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ANIMATION_SCHEDULED_AT_TIME_INTERVAL 
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(updateImageInBackground:) 
                                              userInfo:cell.imageView 
                                               repeats:YES];
    ...
}

- (void) updateImageInBackground:(NSTimer*)aTimer
{  
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateImage:)
                       withObject:[aTimer userInfo]];
}  

- (void) updateImage:(AnimatedImageView*)animatedImageView 
{      
    @autoreleasepool { 
        [animatedImageView refresh];
    }
}  

// In AnimatedImageView.m
-(void)refresh
{
    if(self.currentIndex>=self.urls.count)
        self.currentIndex=0;

    ASIHTTPRequest *request=[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[self.urls objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex]];
    [request startSynchronous];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];

    // How do I cancel this operation if I know that a user performs a scrolling action, therefore departing from this cell.
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performTransition:)
                       withObject:image
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)performTransition:(UIImage*)anImage
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self duration:1.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{ 
        self.image=anImage;
        currentIndex++;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Comment: WWDC 2012 session 211 covers this in some detail, with varying levels of queue cancellation, optimisation and so forth. It's a great video.

Comment: in `cellForRow`, why don't you just set the image to nil when you don't have it immediately? that way, it will be temporarily blank instead of the wrong image.

Comment: @user102008 I did that, but it won't work. The wrong image was already queued in the main thread (`refresh` was in the middle of execution), waiting to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...
Another way to do that would be to put your 'image requesting code' INTO your AnimatedImageView, and invalidate pending request each time you set a new Image URL

```
// your controller
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    ...
    [cell.imageView setDistantImage:imageURL];
    ...    
    }
```

Then, in your Cell class,'setDistantImage' creates an ASIHttpRequest, and invalidates the previous one

```
//your ImageView class

@property (...) ASIHttpRequest *distantImageRequest;

- (void) setDistantImageUrl:(NSUrl *)imageUrl
{
    //clear previous request
    [distantImageRequest clearDelegatesAndCancel];
    //set a new request, with the callBack embedded directly in this ImageView class
    ... 
}

//animation and callBacks methods in this ImageView class too...
```